# Getting a code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } 'Uncaught Exception thrown' in my apple terminal while attempting to run a script

Tags: bash

Sorry in advance because I'm a giant noob to this and probably wont be able to explain it to well. I am attempting to run a script through my apple terminal to connect to an API to a google sheets database to update an app but while the script is running I get 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } 'Uncaught Exception thrown' 
then it logs out. I would prefer not to use process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
as that posses to much of a security risk.

This is my first time using bash so I have not tried anything as I have zero idea what I could do other then TLS_REJECT which I would

What I get when it runs:

```
mobenode.js v8.0 1/2/18
errorlogfile=/Users/dgibson/Desktop/GoogleSheets/Import.log
googlespreadsheet=11tKwNspYirKIV7JK7FzoJ9VnWL0CVEx9OeHtSpTHZ
google login
HOST:https://sales.mobe.com
sesstoken found in sheet
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1116:38)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:643:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:473:38) code:                                                                      .   'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' } 'Uncaught Exception thrown'
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

What I expect to get is the app to update

Heres my script:

```
DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`
echo $DIRNAME

$DIRNAME/framework/node $DIRNAME/framework/googlesheeter/googlesheeter.js /errorlogfile="$DIRNAME/Import.log" /googlespreadsheet=11tKwNspYirKIV7JK7FzoJ9VnWL0CVEx9OeHtSpTHZ
```

Comment: Just did, sorry I forgot to put it in their orignally